# Writing huge amount of physical file names into text files c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have developed a small tool that will be used to display data discrepancy in c#, what I do is explained point wise below,

1. fetch data from database and write list of file names in text file based on date criteria -output 1
2. take dir of path 1 and write into text file- output2
3. take dir of path2, path3 and path4 similarly and write into text files separately for each path- output 3/4/5
4. compare option: compare output1 and 2 and write down the difference in text file, this difference is then compared to output3 and again the difference is written in another file, and so on...
5. my issue is : my last path has more than 2.5 million records of files, whenever I try writing it in text file it hangs the application and it never provides output, I did try filtering it with date criteria but even for a single day where records could be around 30 thousands it hangs

I have searched many sites but did not get solution that I can understand or able to implement it. Below is my attempted code.

```
if (!txtpath3.Text.Equals(String.Empty) && System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(txtpath3.Text).Length > 0)
{
    var directory = txtpath3.Text;
    var from_dt = this.dtpickerstart.Value;
    var end_dt = this.dtpickerend.Value;

    DateTime from_date = from_dt;
    DateTime to_date = end_dt;

    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
    FileSystemInfo[] files = di.GetFileSystemInfos();

    var op = di.GetFiles()
        .Where(file => file.LastWriteTime >= from_date && file.LastWriteTime <= to_date);

    foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(txtpath3.Text, "*.*"))
    {
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(dirfile3, true);
        tw.WriteLine("" + file + "");
        tw.Close();
    }
}
else
{

}
```

Comment: What is a LACS? Some kind of unit?

Comment: @nvoigt Lac (or Lakh) is Indian measurement for 100 000

Comment: Ok, that's a lot. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `foreach`-loop opens and closes the file for all lines. You should open and close the file outside of the loop.

```
using(var tw = new StreamWriter(dirfile3, true))
{
    foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(txtpath3.Text, "*.*"))
    {
        tw.WriteLine("" + file + "");
    }
}
```

Even easier would be using the already existing functions to do this:

```
File.AppendAllLines(dirfile3, System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(txtpath3.Text, "*.*"));
```

As 2.5 million filesnames are a lot to keep in RAM at the same time, you might be better off with just enumerating them:

```
File.AppendAllLines(dirfile3, System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(txtpath3.Text, "*.*"));
```

Comment: Thanks bro , I have tested your suggested points and working on 100 thousand, I will test it on 2500 thousands records later today and confirm

Comment: When I am trying it on 2500000 records , it's just not responding, I checked it in debug mode and my debugger dost not proceed after below code , it tries to load all files in var op which hangs the process .                                                                      var op = di.GetFiles()         .Where(file => file.LastWriteTime >= from_date && file.LastWriteTime <= to_date);

Comment: Do not use GetFiles. It will load a full list of the files into RAM. Try `EnumerateFiles` instead.

Comment: Now it is taking approx 10 minutes to fetch details out of 2500 thousands  thank you so much all , specially nvoigt 

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is in the `foreach`

```
foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(txtpath3.Text, "*.*"))
{
   TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(dirfile3, true);
   tw.WriteLine("" + file + "");
   tw.Close();
}
```

For each and every one of the many, many files, you are opening a file, appending a line, and closing the file, only to open it again, write another line, etc, etc...

You should just prepare everything in a string first, and then just insert all the text in one go, something like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(txtpath3.Text, "*.*"))
{
   sb.AppendLine(file);
}
File.WriteAllText(dirfile3, sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Seems unnecessary to create the string in memory first. Better just to write the files to the target directly. (without opening and closing a stream writer all the time of course)

Comment: @Magnus, I agree. I was shooting for a more generalist approach, if the source is not already in a convenient `string[]`